# Зависает UBUNTU 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Компьютер зависает (мышкой вводить можно) после того как я либо перезагружаю, выключаю компьютер, захожу в параметры системы. Не знаю в чем причина, помогите, программировать надо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема была связана с видюхой NVIDIA. так что устанавливайте драйвера на вашу видюху и проблема решится